# В Debian 11 ошибка приложения(Redbot Discord) запуска службы при загрузке системы

Tags: discord, бот

Установил и настроил бота для дискорда REDBOT. Все работает если запускать командой
sudo systemctl start(или рестарт) red@bot.service
Но если отправить систему в перезагрузку, то бот не стартует, а выкидывает ошибки(Служба пишет, что активна)

```html
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]: [2022-05-16 20:05:54] [CRITICAL] red.main: Caught unhandled exception in event loop:
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]: Exception in callback <function Downloader.create_init_task.<locals>._done_callback at 0x7f6651f0e670>
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]: Traceback (most recent call last):
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:   File "/home/123123/redenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redbot/cogs/downloader/downloader.py", line 113, in initialize
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:     await self._repo_manager.initialize()
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:   File "/home/123123/redenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redbot/cogs/downloader/repo_manager.py", line 1022, in initialize
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:     await self._load_repos(set_repos=True)
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:   File "/home/123123/redenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redbot/cogs/downloader/repo_manager.py", line 1218, in _load_repos
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:     ret[folder.stem] = await Repo.from_folder(folder, branch)
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:   File "/home/123123/redenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redbot/cogs/downloader/repo_manager.py", line 1007, in from_folder
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:     await repo.checkout(repo.branch, force_checkout=True)
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:   File "/home/123123/redenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redbot/cogs/downloader/repo_manager.py", line 588, in _checkout
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:     p = await self._run(git_command)
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:   File "/home/123123/redenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redbot/cogs/downloader/repo_manager.py", line 560, in _run
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:     p: CompletedProcess = await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]: asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]: Traceback (most recent call last):
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:   File "uvloop/cbhandles.pyx", line 63, in uvloop.loop.Handle._run
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:   File "/home/123123/redenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redbot/cogs/downloader/downloader.py", line 100, in _done_callback
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]:     exc = task.exception()
мая 16 20:05:54 123123 python3.9[1698]: asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

Помогите, я пока с debian на "вы". Спасибо!

Comment: Когда попытался добавить через cron (С помощью скрипта запуска) То тоже бот стартует с ошибками, как буд то он работает только после входа юзера.(когда вручную скрипт стартую, запускается)

Answer (score 0):

В общем то нашел решение, бот долбился в ipv6.После отключения в debian ipv6 все стало стартовать и dns заработал, а болт запустился!